# How to layer a (non-responsive) map image over a background image

Tags: html, css

I want an image of a map placed centered and in front of an image of a brick background. One image is saved as a "jpeg" and the other "jpg". Not sure if that makes a difference. Both images show on my page, but stacked vertically.

My HTML:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <img src="OH-map.jpeg"/>
    <img src="BRICK.jpg"/> 
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#container OH-map{ position: absolute; } 
#container BRICK{ background-size: cover; background-color: inherit; }
```

Comment: Welcome. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Johannes Sure you can use filenames by using selectors `[src="FILENAME.jpg"]` or `[src^="FILENAME"]`. I wouldn't do it, but it's possible.

Comment: @RickardElimää I am aware of that, but as you say, one wouldn't do it, that's really what classes and IDs are for. BTW, I wonder why my comment disappeared - I basically wrote the same that isherwood wrote in his answer...

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is faulty. You've written selectors that look for elements by type (`OH-map` and `BRICK`). Obviously those elements don't exist. Instead, give those elements classes and target them in your CSS:

```
<div id="container"> 
    <img src="BRICK.jpg" class="brick-image" /> 
    <img src="OH-map.jpeg" class="map-image" />
</div> 

#container .map-image { position: absolute; } 
#container .brick-image { background-size: cover; background-color: inherit; }
```

A few other notes:

- Since you want the map *over* the background it should come second in your markup
- Absolute positioning probably isn't necessary here--put your brick image on the container as a background instead, which will clean up your markup by eliminating one element

```css
#container {
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1200/880000); /* /size/color */
  background-size: cover; /* zoom and crop image to fill the entire element */
  display: flex; /* modern content layout strategy */
  flex-direction: column; /* the default is "row" */
  justify-content: center; /* main axis (vertical) alignment */
  align-items: center; /* cross-axis (horizontal) alignment */
  min-height: 180px;  /* demo only */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
</div>
```

[Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: No problem. Please do [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thank you comments are discouraged.